# Looking for a book about a huge war with dragons

Tags: story-identification

I have years ago read a book about some fantasy world where 2 huge factions are fighting in a medieval setting but with dragons as an airforce.
The main character joins a group of dragon riders travelling as a kind of circus before later joining a military unit of dragon riders and going to war.
The book was part of a at least 2-3 books' series and I remember that I really liked it. I can't remember the exact title though (although I am pretty sure it had "dragon" in it).

It is not the Naomi Novik series about napoleons drakes.

Can anyone help me find it?

Comment: Game of thrones?!

Comment: *pssh* Who's going to write a book about wars and dragons? Both are such boring subjects...

Comment: [Dragonlance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragonlance) D&D scenario, some tales, chronicles and novels can be waht you are looking for

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would have never thought that there are so many books matching my description. I have finally found the book I was looking for though:

it is the [Dragonmaster Series by Chris Bunch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chris_Bunch#Dragonmaster_Trilogy), which includes *Storm of Wings* (2002), *Knighthood of the Dragon* (2003), and *The Last Battle* (2004).

> Dragonmaster is an action trilogy following the life and exploits of Hal Kailas, a peasant who left home at an early age. During his early years Hal must work as a casual laborer. His dream is to fly dragons, so he joins a traveling troupe who give rides on dragons as entertainment from town to town. Hal is away from his home country and his king, Asir. When war breaks out, he is drafted into the army as an unwilling soldier. However, he does his best and works his way through the ranks of the army and society with his heroic exploits. Dragons are mainly wild and untamed creatures that are brought into the war, while Hal and others devise new and more damaging ways to use the dragons against their enemies. This tale is told in the first two books, which contain bloody action throughout. The third book covers life after the war, the difficulties ex-soldiers face, and how Hal deals with it.

Comment: Can you add some more details? so that other users who are looking for a similar book can check this is indeed theirs?

Comment: I just added a link and wikipedias description of the book

Comment: Sounds good, If you can think of any other details, the more details = more attention

Comment: I just did. Thanks again for everyone's help!

Comment: Sounds like an interesting series. Too bad it doesn't seem to exist in kindle :(

Answer (score 6):

Could this be the *[Age of Fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_Fire)* series by E. E. Knight? The summary of the second book, *Dragon Avenger*:

> *Dragon Avenger* follows Wistala, the sole surviving female. After being separated from Auron, she tracks down their gravely-injured father and spends some weeks nursing him back to health. However, Wistala and AuRel are found by the dragon hunter Drakossozh, and after her father is killed she is forced to leap into a gorge to escape. She is rescued, unconscious and near death, by a kindhearted elf named Rainfall who becomes an adoptive father to the orphan. During her stay with Rainfall, Wistala becomes involved in a conspiracy by the local thane Hammar to claim Mossbell, Rainfall's ancestral home. She later travels with a circus as a fortune teller, briefly roaming the land after uncasing her wings in search of dragons who can help her avenge her family's deaths. After an unsuccessful meeting with a small group of ambivalent dragons in the north, Wistala returns to the circus and wins favor with a dwarf named Gobold Fangbreaker, the ruler of the Wheel of Fire and the same dwarf responsible for the murder of her parents. Wistala manipulates his downfall from a position of trust, instigating a war between the dwarves and the human barbarians of the north and sabotaging the dwarves, leading to the downfall of the stronghold. Wistala slays Gobold and later encounters the Dragonblade, who agrees to end the bloodshed between their families. The book ends with Wistala preparing to leave in search of AuRon, who she finds is still alive.
>
> *Dragon Avenger* spans the least amount of time of the first three books, following Wistala's first 14 years or so.

There are dragons, a circus, and a war, and the title has "Dragon" in it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but thats not the one I am looking for either. The protagonist in my book is a human (looks like its a dragon here?!). I am not 100% sure about the "dragon" in the title part though.

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like [The Darkness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Darkness_Series) series by Harry Turtledove

Check - 2 huge factions are fighting in a medieval setting
Check - but with dragons as an airforce.
Check - The main character joins a group of dragon riders travelling as a kind of circus
Check - before later joining a military unit of dragon riders and going to war.
Check - The book was part of a at least 2-3 books' series

Answer (score 4):

Is it [Dragonflight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragonflight), part of the [Dragon Riders of Pern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragonriders_of_Pern) series by Anne McCaffrey?

Plot summary of the world and books:

> Life on Pern as presented in the novels resembles a pre-industrial society with lords, holds, harpers (musicians, entertainers, and teachers), and dragons, with the occasional examples of higher technology (like flamethrowers, telegraphs, chemical fertilizers, and powerful microscopes and telescopes).
>
> Pernese people are described as belonging to four basic groups: Weyrfolk (including Dragonriders) who live in the Weyrs, the Holders who live in the Holds (cities, towns and farms), the crafters who live in Crafthalls (or are assigned to work their crafts in certain Holds), and the Holdless who have no permanent home (including traders, displaced Holders, and brigands).
>
> One of the main threats to Pernese civilization in the series is Thread, which is described as a mycorrhizoid spore that periodically rains down on the planet due to the orbit of the Red Star. The Red Star is set out to be a rogue planet in the Rukbat system. The Red Star, characterized as a "Sedna-class inner Oort cloud object", has a 250 Turn (or Pernese year) elliptic orbit around its sun. Thread can reach the planet Pern for about 50 Turns while the Red Star is at perihelion. Thread is described in this series as an agent that consumes organic material at a voracious rate, including crops, animals, and any humans in its path.
>
> The Pernese use intelligent firebreathing dragons and their riders to fight Thread. The riders have a telepathic bond with their dragons, formed by Impression at the dragon's hatching. Later books deal with the initial colonization of Pern and the creation of the dragons through genetic manipulation. The lengthy time period covered by the series as a whole (over two and a half millennia) allows room for new stories and characters, explored by each new novel released by the authors.

Comment: Sadly thats not the one. Although its on my "have-to-read" list too

Comment: I think after looking it up I might have to read it too

Comment: Haha have fun! I read the first one years ago and its quite good. Planning to read the following ones soon. PS and Brandon Sanderson recommends it ;)

Comment: You can't call yourself a serious reader of SF&F if you haven't read at least *Dragonflight* and *Dragonquest*. If you're on the younger side (pre-teen or early teens), maybe start instead with *Dragonsong* and *Dragonsinger*. (Each of those is a trilogy, but in both trilogies the third book follows different characters, and can thus be disappointing if you read them immediately after reading the first two books.)